# Will it be possible to autohide indicators in some way in the future?

Tags: unity, indicator

Currently I have way to many indicators/icons on my system tray. Is it possible that auto hide will be added in future Ubuntu versions?

Comment: =) hi poolie how r ya?

Comment: As long as we don't get a Windows "they autohide, and when you tell them not to, they autohide"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have too many indicators then some of your indicators probably shouldn't be indicators. Perhaps take a look at the [Design guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomStatusMenuDesignGuidelines) to work out which ones these are.

(This is my personal view, I'm not sure how it tallies with the view of the Ayatana team.)

Comment: I personally agree partly in the sense that some indicators really don't need to be (in the way they currently are - that is they could be amalgamated as KDE does with some things) but still autohide should be an option.

Comment: Yes, chat with the author of the indicators about fitting into one of the category indicators, like sound, messaging etc.

Comment: @Mark Shuttleworth @fluteflute thanks :) - P.S. I still want a hiding option, but that could work :P