# Can I temporarily hide indicators to reduce clutter?

Tags: indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I blacklist an appindicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54429/can-i-blacklist-an-appindicator)

I currently have 9 indicators (old-style and new-style appindicators) sitting in my Ubuntu taskbar. In time I'm sure some of them will migrate to a better location (for example, I presume both SpiderOak and Dropbox are supposed to be under the mail indicator, just like Ubuntu One). Until then, I want to reduce the clutter!

In Windows there is an option to hide (but not [remove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54429/can-i-blacklist-an-appindicator)) system tray icons.[1] When you click on a reveal button, the hidden icons are revealed and you can use them as normal. Is there a similar function in Ubuntu?

[1] I could remove old-style non-appindicators from the `systray-whitelist`, but it would be a major hassle when I want to show them again.

Comment: Based on this the answer might be no - http://askubuntu.com/questions/21125/will-it-be-possible-to-autohide-indicators-in-some-way-in-the-future - right now I'm looking for a yes/no/how-to answer, not a discussion about the rightness of the indicators or how to design them. Let's imagine I'm stuck with them :)

Comment: expanded http://askubuntu.com/questions/54429/can-i-blacklist-an-appindicator to include relevant bits missing from this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no such an option in Unity and as far as I've seen Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't have it either.