# What do I need to tell a developer if I want them to move their indicator under a system indicator menu?

Tags: indicator, menu, application-development

As a follow-up to [my question on reducing indicator clutter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61514/can-i-hide-indicators-to-reduce-clutter) and the [implication that apps are supposed to group themselves under existing indicators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21125/will-it-be-possible-to-autohide-indicators-in-some-way-in-the-future) I'd like to submit requests to one or four developers to group their apps accordingly.

What resources exist to help developers do this?

- Are there existing guidelines on **where** apps should group themselves?

  - For example, SpiderOak and Dropbox presumably ought to follow the example of Ubuntu One, but what about Truecrypt or Transmission Remote GUI?
- Are there existing guides/tutorials on **how** to create a working subindicator?
- What if they use **libraries other than Gnome**? (For example, if they use Qt)
- Are there any **known pitfalls**?
- How can they easily **future-proof** their work?
- Would any of this work be beneficial to deployment **outside Ubuntu**?

Comment: unlike default indicators i.e. `datetime`, `power/system`, `messages`, `me` other indicators must have a disable option or quit option. Could you be more clear on what indicators you are using ?

Comment: @sargarchalise Dropbox, hamster-indicator (for hamster-applet) SpiderOak, Transmission Remote GUI, Truecrypt, Wakoopa, and as of today Chromium and Chrome (after installing Offline Gmail on both) - just in case I've been unclear I want them to keep running, just move them

Comment: @sargarchalise and Skype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems (but I'm not 100% sure) that moving application indicators under system indicator menus requires Canonical to develop a spec for such integration. Unless an existing spec exists (for example, music player integration with the Sound Menu), asking a third-party application developer to move their indicator under a system indicator doesn't make sense.

The available system menus are [listed in this 11.04 help doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/unity-appmenu-intro.html).

Some integration specs I found:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SessionMenu (no integration points I know of)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu (music player integration)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu (IM, email and microblogging integration)

  - apparently [UbuntuOne shouldn't be here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu#Ubuntu_One)

The [Me Menu will be dropped in 11.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/ubuntu-11-10-menu-goodbye/) and related integration has moved to the Messaging Menu.